# Echarts. How update two series in realtimie chart?

Tags: echarts

I have realtime chart https://codepen.io/xnkka/pen/qBdNpmo, which has two series, updating with setOption work only to one of the series. How fix this?

```
myChart.setOption({
    xAxis: {
      data: startDataCat,
    },
    series: [{
      data: startDataVal
    },
    {
      data: startDataVal2
    },
    ]
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked your code, seems like you have missed to remove the value from second dataset. You forgot to add the below statement where you remove the data from front of second dataset.

startDataVal2.shift();

I have updated your code and made the following post.

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
    var dataCount = 500;
    var data = generateData(dataCount);
    var data2 = generateData(dataCount);
    var startDataCat = data.categoryData.slice(0, 250);
    var endDataCat = data.categoryData.slice(250);
    var startDataVal = data.valueData.slice(0, 250);
    var startDataVal2 = data2.valueData.slice(0, 250);
    var endDataVal = data.valueData.slice(250);
    var endDataVal2 = data2.valueData.slice(250);

    var option = {
      title: {
        text: "live chart",//
        left: 10
      },
      toolbox: {
        feature: {
          dataZoom: {
            yAxisIndex: false
          },
          saveAsImage: {
            pixelRatio: 2
          }
        }
      },
      legend: {
        data: ['first', 'second'],
       
    },
      tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer: {
          type: 'shadow'
        }
      },      
      grid: {
        bottom: 90
      },
      dataZoom: [{
        type: 'inside'
      }, {
        type: 'slider'
      }],
      xAxis: {
        data: startDataCat,
        silent: false,
        splitLine: {
          show: false
        },
        splitArea: {
          show: false
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        splitArea: {
          show: false
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'first',
        type: 'line',
        data: startDataVal,
        // Set `large` for large data amount
        large: true
      },
      {
        name: 'second',
        type: 'line',
        data: startDataVal2,
        // Set `large` for large data amount
        large: true
      }
      ]
    };
    setInterval(function () {
      startDataCat.shift();
      startDataCat.push(endDataCat.shift())
      startDataVal.shift();
      startDataVal2.shift();
      startDataVal.push(endDataVal.shift())
      startDataVal2.push(endDataVal2.shift())
      myChart.setOption({
        xAxis: {
          data: startDataCat,
        },
        series: [{
          data: startDataVal
        },
        {
          data: startDataVal2
        },
        ]
      });
    }, 1000);
    function generateData(count) {
      var baseValue = Math.random() * 1000;
      var time = +new Date(2020, 1, 1);
      var smallBaseValue;

      function next(idx) {
        smallBaseValue = idx % 30 === 0
          ? Math.random() * 700
          : (smallBaseValue + Math.random() * 500 - 250);
        baseValue += Math.random() * 20 - 10;
        return Math.max(
          0,
          Math.round(baseValue + smallBaseValue) + 3000
        );
      }

      var categoryData = [];
      var valueData = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        categoryData.push(echarts.format.formatTime('yyyy-MM-dd\nhh:mm:ss', time));
        valueData.push(next(i).toFixed(2));
        time += 1000;
      }

      return {
        categoryData: categoryData,
        valueData: valueData
      };
    }
    myChart.setOption(option)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main" style="width:1000px; height:400px;"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.6.0/echarts.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```